# Fullscreen mode for tablets browsers and mobile phone browsers when playing HTML5 video

Tags: html, video, mobile-safari

On mobile phone, iPhone for example, video playing is always in fullscreen mode, but not in iPad. Does it mean the two browsers are different, OR they are the same but the kernel of the browser can detect some variable of the device, such as the screensize to force it fullscreen? Most of the time, it is the same case for Android phones and tablets. But I have tried on 4.3 inches HTC Android phones, sometimes the video won't take up the whole screen when the video is playing. Why does this happen?

And a further question is that is it possible that some video file could be played using HTML5 video tag on iPad but not on iPhone (and Android devices)? Or the other way round?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how it works with the detection of fullscreen or not, but I do know that the HTML5 videotag does work on both iPad and iPhone, only iPhone will play it fullscreen automatically, but iPad will not automatically play it fullscreen.